# Dynamic dispatch of methods declared outside of classes

Tags: c++, gcc, dynamic-dispatch

I'm trying to understand a library implementation, but the way some methods are dynamically linked, baffles me.
I'm aware of the dispatch mechanisms when using an object of a derived class, but without an object I have no clue how it works.
The library I'm trying to understand is [libitm](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libitm) from the gcc.

The header file [libitm.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libitm/libitm.h) declares all ABI methods as top-level methods without a class or struct around them. And for most of them I found an unique definition, so I have no questions about them and I omit them here. But the following excerpt shows the declaration of 70 methods, whichs definitions baffle me.

```
    typedef uint8_t  _ITM_TYPE_U1;
    typedef uint16_t _ITM_TYPE_U2;
    typedef uint32_t _ITM_TYPE_U4;
    typedef uint64_t _ITM_TYPE_U8;
    typedef float    _ITM_TYPE_F;
    typedef double   _ITM_TYPE_D;
    typedef long double _ITM_TYPE_E;
    typedef float _Complex _ITM_TYPE_CF;
    typedef double _Complex _ITM_TYPE_CD;
    typedef long double _Complex _ITM_TYPE_CE;

    #define ITM_BARRIERS(T) \
      extern _ITM_TYPE_##T _ITM_R##T(const _ITM_TYPE_##T *) ITM_REGPARM;    \
      extern _ITM_TYPE_##T _ITM_RaR##T(const _ITM_TYPE_##T *) ITM_REGPARM;  \
      extern _ITM_TYPE_##T _ITM_RaW##T(const _ITM_TYPE_##T *) ITM_REGPARM;  \
      extern _ITM_TYPE_##T _ITM_RfW##T(const _ITM_TYPE_##T *) ITM_REGPARM;  \
      extern void _ITM_W##T (_ITM_TYPE_##T *, _ITM_TYPE_##T) ITM_REGPARM;   \
      extern void _ITM_WaR##T (_ITM_TYPE_##T *, _ITM_TYPE_##T) ITM_REGPARM; \
      extern void _ITM_WaW##T (_ITM_TYPE_##T *, _ITM_TYPE_##T) ITM_REGPARM;

    ITM_BARRIERS(U1)
    ITM_BARRIERS(U2)
    ITM_BARRIERS(U4)
    ITM_BARRIERS(U8)
    ITM_BARRIERS(F)
    ITM_BARRIERS(D)
    ITM_BARRIERS(E)
    ITM_BARRIERS(CF)
    ITM_BARRIERS(CD)
    ITM_BARRIERS(CE)
```

In the file [dispatch.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libitm/dispatch.h) a struct abi_dispatch is declared, which is used as a base for specific dispatches of TM-algorithms. In this struct the declarations of the 70 methods above are made as pure virtual methods. The following excerpt shows the macro-definition for the methods and the struct.

```
#define ITM_READ_M(T, LSMOD, M, M2)                                         \
  M _ITM_TYPE_##T ITM_REGPARM ITM_##LSMOD##T##M2 (const _ITM_TYPE_##T *ptr) \
  {                                                                         \
    return load(ptr, abi_dispatch::LSMOD);                                  \
  }

#define ITM_READ_M_PV(T, LSMOD, M, M2)                                      \
  M _ITM_TYPE_##T ITM_REGPARM ITM_##LSMOD##T##M2 (const _ITM_TYPE_##T *ptr) \
  = 0;

#define ITM_WRITE_M(T, LSMOD, M, M2)                         \
  M void ITM_REGPARM ITM_##LSMOD##T##M2 (_ITM_TYPE_##T *ptr, \
                     _ITM_TYPE_##T val)  \
  {                                                          \
    store(ptr, val, abi_dispatch::LSMOD);                    \
  }

#define ITM_WRITE_M_PV(T, LSMOD, M, M2)                      \
  M void ITM_REGPARM ITM_##LSMOD##T##M2 (_ITM_TYPE_##T *ptr, \
                     _ITM_TYPE_##T val)  \
  = 0;

#define CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T(T, M, M2) \
  ITM_READ_M(T, R, M, M2)                \
  ITM_READ_M(T, RaR, M, M2)              \
  ITM_READ_M(T, RaW, M, M2)              \
  ITM_READ_M(T, RfW, M, M2)              \
  ITM_WRITE_M(T, W, M, M2)               \
  ITM_WRITE_M(T, WaR, M, M2)             \
  ITM_WRITE_M(T, WaW, M, M2)
#define CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV(T, M, M2) \
  ITM_READ_M_PV(T, R, M, M2)                \
  ITM_READ_M_PV(T, RaR, M, M2)              \
  ITM_READ_M_PV(T, RaW, M, M2)              \
  ITM_READ_M_PV(T, RfW, M, M2)              \
  ITM_WRITE_M_PV(T, W, M, M2)               \
  ITM_WRITE_M_PV(T, WaR, M, M2)             \
  ITM_WRITE_M_PV(T, WaW, M, M2)

#define CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS(M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (U1, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (U2, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (U4, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (U8, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (F, M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (D, M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (E, M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (CF, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (CD, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T (CE, M, M2)
#define CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_PV(M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (U1, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (U2, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (U4, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (U8, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (F, M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (D, M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (E, M, M2)  \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (CF, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (CD, M, M2) \
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_T_PV (CE, M, M2)

struct abi_dispatch
{
public:
  enum ls_modifier { NONTXNAL, R, RaR, RaW, RfW, W, WaR, WaW };

public:
  CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS_PV(virtual, )
}
```

The derived structs of abi_dispatch can be found for example in [method-ml](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libitm/method-ml.cc) or [method-gl](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libitm/method-gl.cc). They use CREATE_DISPATCH_METHODS(virtual, ) and the above macro to generate the 70 read/write methods and map them to load/store template functions.

My big question is: How does the run-time system know which method definition(the one in method-gl or method-ml) should be used when one of the library functions is called? In the definition of the read/write methods, there is no abi_dispatch object mentioned. There is an abi-dispatch object present in the thread-local storage, but I don't know how that fits in with this.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Found the missing link.

There's another macro (CREATE_DISPATCH_FUNCTIONS) that defines the 70 function declarations from above and calls the appropriate Methods in the dispatch object.